# Why does Odata (through Teiid) only display certain tables and not others?

Tags: odata, teiid

I set up a Teiid instance to view a variety of tables. When I set up the VDB, I specified a number of tables to show up:

[image]

**However**, when I view the XML in chrome (http://www.someserver.com:8080/odata/JTrac) only SDM_2D_LINE_TRACKER shows up:

[image]

Any idea why this is? Why don't the other tables show up? If I look under "TABLES" some table names show up (http://www.someserver.com:8080/odata/JTrac/Tables). Here's a sampling of the XML, but you can see that ATTACHMENTS, CALENDAR and so forth show up:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xml:base="http://amr-dsiprod05:8080/odata/JTrac/"><title type="text">Tables</title><id>http://amr-dsiprod05:8080/odata/JTrac//Tables</id><updated>2014-06-26T21:00:34Z</updated><link rel="self" title="Tables" href="Tables"/><entry><id>http://amr-dsiprod05:8080/odata/JTrac/Tables(Name='ATTACHMENTS',SchemaName='JTracOracle',VDBName='JTrac')</id><title type="text"/><updated>2014-06-26T21:00:34Z</updated><author><name/></author><link rel="edit" title="Tables" href="Tables(Name='ATTACHMENTS',SchemaName='JTracOracle',VDBName='JTrac')"/><link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Columns" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="Columns" href="Tables(Name='ATTACHMENTS',SchemaName='JTracOracle',VDBName='JTrac')/Columns"/><link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/KeyColumns" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="KeyColumns" href="Tables(Name='ATTACHMENTS',SchemaName='JTracOracle',VDBName='JTrac')/KeyColumns"/><link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Keys" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="Keys" href="Tables(Name='ATTACHMENTS',SchemaName='JTracOracle',VDBName='JTrac')/Keys"/><link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Schemas" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="Schemas" href="Tables(Name='ATTACHMENTS',SchemaName='JTracOracle',VDBName='JTrac')/Schemas"/><category term="SYS.Tables" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/><content type="application/xml"><m:properties><d:OID m:type="Edm.Int32" m:null="true"/><d:Description m:null="true"/><d:Type>Table</d:Type><d:IsSystem m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:IsSystem><d:IsMaterialized m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:IsMaterialized><d:Name>ATTACHMENTS</d:Name><d:NameInSource>"JTRAC"."ATTACHMENTS"</d:NameInSource><d:Cardinality m:type="Edm.Int32">-1</d:Cardinality><d:UID>mmuuid:2967df2e-4904-4bb7-9854-1f21a90e5f8a</d:UID><d:IsPhysical m:type="Edm.Boolean">true</d:IsPhysical><d:SupportsUpdates m:type="Edm.Boolean">true</d:SupportsUpdates><d:VDBName>JTrac</d:VDBName><d:SchemaName>JTracOracle</d:SchemaName></m:properties></content></entry><entry><id>http://amr-dsiprod05:8080/odata/JTrac/Tables(Name='CALENDAR',SchemaName='JTracOracle',VDBName='JTrac')</id><title type="text"/><updated>2014-06-26T21:00:34Z</updated><author><name/></author><link rel="edit" title="Tables" href="Tables(Name='CALENDAR',SchemaName='JTracOracle',VDBName='JTrac')"/><link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Columns" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="Columns" href="Tables(Name='CALENDAR',SchemaName='JTracOracle',VDBName='JTrac')/Columns"/><link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/KeyColumns" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="KeyColumns" href="Tables(Name='CALENDAR',SchemaName='JTracOracle',VDBName='JTrac')/KeyColumns"/><link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Keys" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="Keys" href="Tables(Name='CALENDAR',SchemaName='JTracOracle',VDBName='JTrac')/Keys"/><link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Schemas" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="Schemas" href="Tables(Name='CALENDAR',SchemaName='JTracOracle',VDBName='JTrac')/Schemas"/><category term="SYS.Tables" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/><content type="application/xml"><m:properties><d:OID m:type="Edm.Int32" m:null="true"/><d:Description m:null="true"/><d:Type>Table</d:Type><d:IsSystem m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:IsSystem><d:IsMaterialized m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:IsMaterialized><d:Name>CALENDAR</d:Name><d:NameInSource>"JTRAC"."CALENDAR"</d:NameInSource><d:Cardinality m:type="Edm.Int32">-1</d:Cardinality><d:UID>mmuuid:1447f956-9880-402e-8dc6-58aac15c1df9</d:UID><d:IsPhysical m:type="Edm.Boolean">true</d:IsPhysical><d:SupportsUpdates m:type="Edm.Boolean">true</d:SupportsUpdates><d:VDBName>JTrac</d:VDBName><d:SchemaName>JTracOracle</d:SchemaName></m:properties></content></entry>
```

What's special about SDM_2D_LINE_TRACKER that it shows up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the table has identity key (primary key) specified it will show up. OData entity look up mechanism requires identity based lookup. If a table is being skipped, there will be log entry notifying the user as such.